Dart Range start error (Range start 14 is out of text of length 13)
I am trying to write a phone number formatter
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class NumberTextInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    final int newTextLength = newValue.text.length;
    int selectionIndex = newValue.selection.end;
    int usedSubstringIndex = 0;
    final StringBuffer newText = StringBuffer();

    if (newTextLength >= 1) {
      newText.write('+');
      if (newValue.selection.end >= 1) selectionIndex++;
    }
    if (newTextLength >= 3) {
      if (newValue.text.substring(0, usedSubstringIndex = 1) == '1') {
        newText.write('${newValue.text.substring(0, usedSubstringIndex = 1)} ');
      } else {
        newText.write('${newValue.text.substring(0, usedSubstringIndex = 2)} ');
      }
      if (newValue.selection.end >= 2) selectionIndex += 1;
    }
    // Dump the rest.
    if (newTextLength >= usedSubstringIndex) {
      newText.write(newValue.text.substring(usedSubstringIndex));
    }

    return TextEditingValue(
      text: truncateBuffer(newText, usedSubstringIndex+12),
      selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: selectionIndex),
    );
  }

  static String truncateBuffer(StringBuffer value, int maxLength) {
    print(value.length);
    print(maxLength);
    if (value.length>maxLength) {
      print('truncating triggered~~~');
      return value.toString().substring(0, maxLength) ;
    }else {
      return value.toString();
    }
  }
}


If the country code starts with 1 I would like the total length of the formatted string to be 13 , e.g. '+1 222333444' and if it starts with anything else, there should be a length of 14: '+99 222333444'
I am recieving the error:
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY SERVICES LIBRARY
╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
═════
The following assertion was thrown during method call
TextInputClient.updateEditingState:
Range start 14 is out of text of length 13
'package:flutter/src/services/text_input.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1015 pos 12: 'range.start >= 0
&& range.start <= text.length'

Either the assertion indicates an error in the
framework itself, or we should provide substantially
more information in this error message to help you
determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing
a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?templa
  te=2_bug.yml

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#2      TextEditingValue._textRangeIsValid
(package:flutter/src/services/text_input.dart:1015:12)
#3      TextEditingValue.toJSON
(package:flutter/src/services/text_input.dart:970:12)
#4      _PlatformTextInputControl.setEditingState
(package:flutter/src/services/text_input.dart:2312:13)
#5      TextInput._setEditingState
(package:flutter/src/services/text_input.dart:1993:15)
#6      TextInputConnection.setEditingState
(package:flutter/src/services/text_input.dart:1435:25)
#7
EditableTextState._updateRemoteEditingValueIfNeeded
(package:flutter/src/widgets/editable_text.dart:3525:2
7)
#8      EditableTextState.endBatchEdit
(package:flutter/src/widgets/editable_text.dart:3514:5
)
#9      EditableTextState._formatAndSetValue
(package:flutter/src/widgets/editable_text.dart:4208:5
)
#10     EditableTextState.updateEditingValue
(package:flutter/src/widgets/editable_text.dart:3246:7
)
#11     TextInput._updateEditingValue
(package:flutter/src/services/text_input.dart:2067:43)
#12     TextInput._handleTextInputInvocation
(package:flutter/src/services/text_input.dart:1903:29)
#13     TextInput._loudlyHandleTextInputInvocation
(package:flutter/src/services/text_input.dart:1803:20)
#14     MethodChannel._handleAsMethodCall
(package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:57
1:55)
#15     MethodChannel.setMethodCallHandler.<anonymous
closure>
(package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:56
4:34)
#16
_DefaultBinaryMessenger.setMessageHandler.<anonymous
closure>
(package:flutter/src/services/binding.dart:618:35)
#17     _invoke2 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:344:13)
#18     _ChannelCallbackRecord.invoke
(dart:ui/channel_buffers.dart:45:5)
#19     _Channel.push
(dart:ui/channel_buffers.dart:135:31)
#20     ChannelBuffers.push
(dart:ui/channel_buffers.dart:343:17)
#21     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPlatformMessage
(dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:750:22)
#22     _dispatchPlatformMessage
(dart:ui/hooks.dart:257:31)
(elided 2 frames from class _AssertionError)

call:
  MethodCall(TextInputClient.updateEditingState, [1,
  {selectionBase: 14, composingExtent: -1,
  selectionAffinity: TextAffinity.downstream, text: +1
  22233344445, selectionIsDirectional: false,
  selectionExtent: 14, composingBase: -1}])
══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
══════════════════════════════════════════════

As you can see in my code, I am trying to make sure the buffer is long enough before I try to truncate the string, but I am still receiving that error.
As I continue to type in the input, I continuously get this error despite the buffer being plenty long enough.
...
Another exception was thrown: Range start 37 is out of
text of length 13
flutter: 38
flutter: 13
flutter: truncating triggered~~~
Another exception was thrown: Range start 38 is out of
text of length 13
flutter: 39
flutter: 13
flutter: truncating triggered~~~
Another exception was thrown: Range start 39 is out of
text of length 13
flutter: 40
flutter: 13
flutter: truncating triggered~~~
Another exception was thrown: Range start 40 is out of
text of length 13
...

Any thoughts?
EDITED to show implementation:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_form_builder/flutter_form_builder.dart';
import 'package:form_builder_validators/form_builder_validators.dart';
import 'package:heard/ui/views/phone_formatter.dart';

class PeopleForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => _PeopleFormState();
}

class _PeopleFormState extends State<PeopleForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>();
  final _mobileFormatter = NumberTextInputFormatter();


@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FormBuilder(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          ...
          Row(
            children: [
              ...
              Flexible(
                  fit: FlexFit.tight,
                  child: FormBuilderTextField(
                    name: 'phone',
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                      FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                      _mobileFormatter
                    ],
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Phone Number',
                    ),
                    validator: FormBuilderValidators.compose([
                      FormBuilderValidators.required(),
                    ]),
                  ))
            ],
          ),
          ...
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


Can you post how you are calling this class so that I can reproduce your error on my end?

You truncate the text but it seems the selectionIndex still refers to the non-truncated text.
